# openmp Fortran--- Code showing same performance

Tags: fortran, openmp, f2py

I am a new user of openmp. I have written the following code in fortran and tried to add parallel feature to it using openmp. Unfortunately, it is taking same time as serial version of this subroutine. I am compiling it using this f2py command. Am sure, I am missing a key concept here but unable to figure it out. Will really appreciate on getting help on this.

!f2py -c  --opt='-O3' --f90flags='-fopenmp' -lgomp  -m g3Test g3TestA.f90

```
exp1 =0.0
exp2 =0.0
exp3 =0.0

!$OMP PARALLEL DO shared(xConfig,s1,s2,s3,c1,c2,c3) private(h)&
!$OMP REDUCTION(+:exp1,exp2,exp3)   
do k=0,numRows-1
    xConfig(0:2) = X(k,0:2)
    do h=0,nPhi-1
        exp1(h) = exp1(h)+exp(-((xConfig(0)-c1(h))**2)*s1)
        exp2(h) = exp2(h)+exp(-((xConfig(1)-c2(h))**2)*s2)
        exp3(h) = exp3(h)+exp(-((xConfig(2)-c3(h))**2)*s3)
    end do
end do 
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO

ALine = exp1+exp2+exp3
```

Comment: How are you measuring the performance? What is the output of f2py (the compiler command it actually executes)? How are you setting the number of threads?

Comment: `xConfig` should be `private`

Comment: What is the value of numRows? How many threads?

Comment: @VladimirF I am using time.time() function in python to measure the parallel and serial code. I am not explicitly setting the number of threads, but i guess i should. f2py output compiles it successfully. There are no errors or warnings

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thanks. Corrected the code but still same performance.

Comment: @IanBush numRows change with every time I call the fortran code. They can be anywhere from 1 to 200. I am not explicitly defining number of threads but I guess number of threads should be linked to numRows. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As neatly explained [in this OpenMP Performance training course material from the University of Edinburgh](https://www.archer.ac.uk/training/course-material/2016/08/160802_AdvOpenMP_Bristol/L08-Performance.pdf) for example, there are a number of reasons why OpenMP code does not necessarily scale as you would expect (for example how much of the serial runtime is taken by the part you are parallelising, synchronisation between threads, communication, and other parallel overheads).

You can easily test the performance with different numbers of threads by calling your python script like, e.g. with 2 threads:

```
env OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 python <your script name>
```

and you may consider adding the following lines in your code example to get a *visual confirmation* of the number of threads being used in the OpenMP part of your code:

```
do k=0,numRows-1
    !this if-statement is only for debugging, remove for timing
    !$ if (k==0) then
    !$     print *, 'num_threads running:', OMP_get_num_threads()
    !$ end if
    xConfig(0:2) = X(k,0:2)
```